# No data in Search Analytics > Queries for established site - Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

Over a year ago I set up a landing page for one of my business's software products. I am concerned there is something wrong as `There is no data for this set of filters.` appears under the Queries report in the Google Search Console's Search Analytics section. I find this strange because there are hundreds of clicks and impressions visible in the other reports like the Pages or Countries report.

Since rollout, I have been doing what I can to bring the site in line with Google's SEO best practices. There are no crawl errors, no blocked resources or manual webspam penalties reported and all pages in the submitted sitemap have been indexed (verified by a `site:...` search). There is another site under the same Google account which has almost half the traffic volume, yet over 30 queries reported in the Search Analytics report.

Is there something I may be missing here? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: How recently did you add the site to Google Search Console?   Google can take a few weeks to fill in the data after you add the site, even if the site has been around for a long time.

Comment: Are the redirects, canonical tags, noindex tags, or robots.txt that would prevent Google from indexing the site?   If Google doesn't index it, there will be no data in search analytics.

Comment: The site was added to the Search Console straight after rollout, over a year ago.

Comment: Also, have you added all four variants of the URL to Google Search Console?   `http://example.com`, `https://example.com`, `http://www.example.com`, `https://www.example.com`?   The data will only appear in the one to which Google actually sends traffic.  Sometimes Google sends traffic to multiple.

Comment: The canonical tag's URL matches the URL submitted to the Search Console and  no robots blocking. The site uses `https://...`. all other variants (`http://...` & `www.`) `301` redirect to the correct URL

Comment: And just to be clear, `https://example.com` is the one registered in search console?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Does search console say that pages on the domain are indexed?   If you search for the site can you find it in Google search?

Comment: Yes, the Search Console reports it has indexed all URLs submitted in the sitemap and I have verified that by searching `site:example.com` in Google.

Comment: Then it has me stumped.  Only possibility I see left is that nobody is searching for anything that brings it up.

Answer (score 1):

I can get that same error message if I apply filters that don't match any queries:

[image]

Make sure you reset it to "No filter":

[image]